# MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: null } (mongoDB)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a user controller where I create a user and send it to my mongoDB database. I'm managing to create the account the first time with an empty database, but after I create a user, I can't create another user and I get the error

```
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: null }

  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { username: 1 },
  keyValue: { username: null },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
```

user controller

```
const User = require('../../models/User');

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

class CreateUser {
    async create(req, res) {
        const { name, email, password } = req.body;

        try {
            const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);

            const userAlreadyExists = await User.findOne({ email: email });

            if (userAlreadyExists) {
                return res.status(400).json('User already exists!');
            }

            const user = await User.create({
                name,
                email,
                password: hashedPassword,
            });

            return res.status(200).json(user);
        } catch (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    }
} 

module.exports = new CreateUser ();
```

One strange thing is that my collection just doesn't show up in mongoDB and I don't know how to change it. To connect I used the link

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.5bfp4.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

model user:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment: You set your username to unique in mongoose schema and you're currently trying to add multiple users with the same username `null` (or as you call it `empty space`)

Comment: How can I resolve this?

Comment: either remove the `unique: true;` property from the schema and accept duplicate usernames or use unique usernames (the second option is adviced though)

Comment: I don't have unique: true in the model. I updated the question

Comment: so, from the error and your schema what I can guess is the link (DB) you use already had a collection with the name `users` and you're trying to use a collection with the same name

Comment: Previously I used the link where the user, password and the name of the database were placed. But now, as I showed in the post, the link has a username and password but there is no way for me to choose the name of the database. Do you know how it works?

Comment: either open mongo atlas and reset the collection if you don't need it or user another DB (or another collection but not adviced)